# Named pipe: ReadFile after ConnectNamedPipe return ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, server, named-pipes

I reactivated code that I am sure used to work some months ago. It drives me crazy but it does not anymore. I could not find an answer in other questions.

On the server side, I create a pipe using

```
#define MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH 1024
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, static_cast<PACL>(0), FALSE);

sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

auto pipe_name = _T("\\\\.\\pipe\\") + _serviceName;

HANDLE pipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    pipe_name.c_str(),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
    1, 
    MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, // buffer lengths (advisory)
    0, // default timeout of 50ms when WaitNamedPipe uses NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT
    &sa));
```

Then a thread waits for incoming clients with `ConnectNamedPipe`. `ConnectNamedPipe` blocks until a client connects with

```
HANDLE pipe = CreateFile(
    pipe_name.c_str(),   // pipe name 
    GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,              // no sharing 
    NULL,           // default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // default attributes 
    NULL);         // no template file
```

`ConnectNamedPipe` on the server then returns with `TRUE` and `GetLastError == 0`. But when it tries to call `ReadFile` to read incoming data on the pipe, `ReadFile` immediately returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError==ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`.
On client side, `CreateFile` has returned `GetLastError==231`, "All pipe instances are busy". Although it is the only client! A call to `WaitNamedPipe(pipe, 2000)`returns with error code 121, "The semaphore timeout period has expired". 
Increasing the number of allowed clients in `CreateNamedPipe` does not change anything.

It seems the pipe got completely broken in the moment the client tries to connect. But why? Both client and server run on the same machine with same user and even same session.
Another call to `ConnectNamedPipe` then failed with GLE=232:"The pipe is being closed".

I also had other `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` for `CreateNamedPipe`, which shall allow for non-elevated users to connect, but that makes no difference.

Also I tried to use `CallNamedPipe` on the client with the same result.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly how you are using the pipe on both ends.

Comment: I guess that you have somewhere some rogue program that is connecting to your pipe and then closing. You could try changing the name of the pipe and see if anything changes. If that fails I recommend using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find the cause.

Comment: If @rodrigo's guess is correct (and it seems a good one) it might also be worth trying GetNamedPipeClientProcessId() in the server immediately after ConnectNamedPipe() succeeds.

Comment: I changed the pipe name without success and GetNamedPipeClientProcessId() returns the correct client pid. I will create a complete example (Sorry I focused too much on Minmal... :( )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PathFileExists is the pipe killer! After hours of trying I finally found what breaks the pipe: a simple call to PathFileExists on the pipe name! This was added recently on the client side to check whether the pipe is already created. I had a look at the code changes but I totally missed that. PathFileExists correctly returns true or false but seems to mess up the pipe (as I told it did not help to allow more than one client to connect). Argh!!!

Comment: It's amazing how often building an MCVE can make the cause of the problem obvious. :-)  Thanks for posting back.

Comment: Funny, it looks like `PathFileExists` opens and closes the file, or something like that. So I was partially correct with my guess above. BTW, you should accept this answer, even if it is your own.